# Wordpress: Don't manage to retrieve author's name from php function

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I'm creating a function that sends an email to a mailing list when a post is published on my WordPress blog.

```
function announce_post($post_id){
    $email_address = 'address.of@the-mailing.list';

    $subject = "New Post: " . get_the_title($post_id);
    $body = "Hi,\r\n\r\n" .
        "SOMEONE has just published the article \"" . 
        get_the_title($post_id) . "\" on \"BLOG TITLE\".\r\n\r\n" .     
        "You can read it at " . get_permalink($post_id) . "\r\n" .
        "or visit BLOG_ADDRESS.\r\n\r\n" .
        "Best wishes\r\n" .
        "The Publisher";

    if (wp_mail($email_address, $subject, $body, "From: \"BLOG TITLE\" <address.of@the-blog>")) { }
}

add_action('publish_post','announce_post');
```

As it is the function works well, but of course I would replace the `SOMEONE` with the actual post's author name. And I don't manage to retrieve that.
Neither `get_the_author($post_id)`, `get_post_meta($post_id, 'author_name', true)` nor anything else I tried and can't recall worked. Everything just returned `""`.

So what is the correct way to retrieve the post author's name, given a post id?

Comment: Check the syntax highlighting, see that? Is that a problem in your code, do you get syntax error?

Comment: No, it happened when replacing the blog title with the dummy.

Comment: The function works on the server, now it looks ok here too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_author()` is a (perhaps misleading) function that is intended for use in [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). It's only parameter [is now deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author). It's also worth noting that author data is not stored as post meta, so any `get_post_meta` attempts will be in vain.

You should in fact use `get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id )`. I would suggest accepting the second argument in your hook, which is the `$post` object, to obtain the author ID:

```
function announce_post( $post_id, $post ) {
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
}

add_action( 'publish_post','announce_post', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you. I suppose I'd never found this through the docs myself :-(